# Form drop down for content_type

Tags: django, django-models, content-type, pythonanywhere, generic-foreign-key

please i have the following line of code whose intention is to limit the models presented in the form drop down for the contenttype field to contain only 'Facilitator', 'Enumerator' and 'Tutor' models. This works perfectly on localhost, however when i host the project to python anywhere it doesnt work ie the dropdown shows no options. Please what is wrong?? someone help...

```
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to = {"model__in": ('Facilitator', 'Enumerator', 'Tutor')}, verbose_name="Collected by")
```

Answer (score 1):

The choices are pulled from your database. Are those entries in the database on PythonAnywhere?

Comment: yes...I pulled the code from github with all the models in tact and i've also populated those models with data. Any other suggestions please?

Comment: Could you be using a different version of django on your local computer and on pythonanywhere?  are you [using a virtualenv](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/VirtualEnvForNewerDjango)?

Comment: yes, am using a virtual environment and no the versions are not different, and till date I haven't been able to resolve this issue